# Is every diffeomorphism conformally equivalent to a volume preserving diffeomorphism?

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, algebraic-topology, differential-topology

Let $D \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$ be the **closed** unit disk. Let $f:D \to D$ be a diffeomorphism.

> Does there exist a smooth $h \in C^{\infty}(D)$ such that $h\cdot f$ is an area-preserving diffeomorphism of $D$?

Clearly, such an $h$ must send the entire boundary $\partial D$ either to $1$ or to $-1$. Another necessary condition is $\det\big(d (h\cdot f)\big) = 1$. Since

$$
d (h\cdot f)=h df+dh \otimes f=h df+f \cdot (\nabla h)^T,
$$

by the [matrix determinant lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_determinant_lemma), at all points where $h \neq 0$, we have

$$
\det\big(d (h\cdot f)\big)=h^2\det(df) \big( 1+h^{-1}(\nabla h)^T ((df)^{-1} \cdot f)\big),
$$

so we need to solve the following PDE for $h$

$$\det(df) \cdot \big( h^2+h(\nabla h)^T ((df)^{-1} \cdot f)\big)=1.$$

Comment: Doesn't $h=\dfrac{\pi}{\mathrm{Area}(f(D))}$ always work?

Comment: No, this would only make $\text{Area}(f(D))=\text{Area}(D)$, but I want $\text{Area}(f(S))=\text{Area}(S)$ for every measurable subsets $S \subseteq D$.(which is equivalent to the local property $\det(df)=1$).